# Free DotNetNuke skin resources

Tags: asp.net, open-source, dotnetnuke, skinning

Does anyone have any quality resources for some free (or cheap) DotNetNuke skins?  Most of the skin resources in the DotNetNuke ecosystem are to costly when you need a simple skin for a site that may not turn any revenue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are about ten that have been converted from open source CSS templates available on [DNN Creative](http://skintemplates.dnncreative.com/) that are very high quality for being free.  There are also some gems that can be found for free on [Snowcovered](http://www.snowcovered.com/Snowcovered2/Default.aspx?tabid=295&categoryid=19&sortby=Price-ASC), however be aware that some found there may only be free trials.

The top result on Google for "[free dnn skins](http://www.google.com/search?q=free+dnn+skins)" takes you to [dnnskins.com](http://www.dnnskins.com/free-skins.aspx) but most of those look rather atrocious.

It's relatively easy to convert an open source CSS template into a DotNetNuke skin as well if you have some familiarity with HTML, CSS, and DotNetNuke skinning.

Answer (score 3):

I own http://www.dnnskins.com and you know. These skins you say are atrocious cowgod were done by many a budding developer who thought they were designers too!!  They are in fact Programmer Skins - so you're telling me your own kind here - the programmers of the world are atrocious designers?

While I agree that they aren't that tidy, I've spent months trying to keep them updated to the different versions of DNN and that's proving to be a challenge.

We've converted about 20 css based skins to dnn and made them compliant.

While it's not perfect, it is the best I could muster up, based on my time and efforts and the actual help I have to run this site. It is a bit frustrating to say the least to read about people who bag something, and then, don't even give constructive solutions.

Telling people that it's relatively easy to convert something if you have familiarity really doesn't answer the question here does it?

I wish there were more free sites for dnn skins but the reality is - it's a big job that costs thousand each year to maintain and the motivation was to try and help the dnn community but I can see that people such as your self cowgod have no idea on the work involved in building, managing and providing for the 75,000 or so hungry users.

Cheers and thanks for contributing such positive comments about my site!

Comment: +1 for replying so graciously.

Answer (score 1):

[DNN Creative](http://skintemplates.dnncreative.com/) CSS templates are cool but they have issues with DotNetNuke 5.

For example, there is an inline detection for superuser in "Summer Breeze" skin that results in an error. Even after removing offending code from the skin's ascx I had problems with the containers.

With DNN 4 everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

the best way is to go to your installation Portals/_default/skins/MinimalExtropy folder, simply copy the folder and call it mySkin or whatever you like. There are .ascx files and skin.css file, .ascx file i simply like html file with basic html knowledge you you should be able modify the color schemes. Since this pattern uses the Holy Grail style (look up the internet if you don't know), this should accommodate all your changes. And voila there is you own personal skin. This will automatically show up in skins as long as its in this folder. (Use the file explorer if you are hosting using GoDaddy)